# I'm trying to trigger a directive by using a variable in the class but it is not working

Tags: angularjs

So if I run the following code my directive is triggered and everything works fine.

```
<div class="message"></div>
```

However, if I run `ng-repeat` with one of my variable, the directive is not triggered.

This is my `ng-repeat` statement

```
<div ng-repeat="task in taskList" class="row task-item"  ng-class"task.type">
</div>
```

Here is the directive:

```
myApp.directive('message', [function() {
    return{
        restrict: "C",
        template:'Hello World!',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        }
    }
}])
```

Link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/underwor/apoufhjw/14/)

I could be wrong but I feel like I am overlooking something small. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not going to work ever becuase **ng-class is added after the directives of the element have been collected by angular**. It's too late.

This [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8703) explains it perfeclty.